# Unix cp argument list too long

Tags: unix, ksh, aix

I am using AIX.

When I try to copy all the file in a folder to another folder with the following command:

`cp ./00012524/*.PDF ./dummy01`

The shell complains:

`ksh: /usr/bin/cp: 0403-027 The parameter list is too long.`

How to deal with it? My folder contain 8xxxx files, how can I copy them very fast? each file have size of 4x kb to 1xx kb.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Argument list too long error for rm, cp, mv commands](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11289551/608639)

Comment: Run "ulimit -S -s unlimited" command. Then perform cp/mv/rm operation

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use [find](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_find.htm) command in *nix:

```
find ./00012524 -type f -name "*.PDF" -exec cp {} ./dummy01/ \; -print
```

Comment: In the general case, I would also add a "-type d". Directories matching */PDF should be rare, but for more general copy, it will avoid multiple copies  resulting from copying first the parent directory (or failing at it without the -r flag) then the children.

Answer (score 6):

The *cp* command has a limitation of files which you can copy simultaneous.

One possibility you can copy them using multiple times the cp command bases on your file patterns, like:

```
cp ./00012524/A*.PDF ./dummy01
cp ./00012524/B*.PDF ./dummy01
cp ./00012524/C*.PDF ./dummy01
...
cp ./00012524/*.PDF ./dummy01
```

You can also copy trough *find* command:

```
find ./00012524 -name "*.PDF" -exec cp {} ./dummy01/ \;
```

Comment: I'm getting `omitting directory './00012524'` with the find command.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ ( cd 00012524; ls | grep '\.PDF$' | xargs -I{} cp {} ../dummy01/ )
```

Answer (score 1):

The `-t` flag to `cp` is useful here:

`find ./00012524 -name \*.PDF -print | xargs cp -t ./dummy01`

Answer (score 1):

The best command to copy large number of files from one directory to another.

find  /path/to/source/ -name "*" -exec cp -ruf "{}" /path/to/destination/ \;

This helped me a lot.

Comment: `cp: illegal option -- u`

Answer (score 0):

You should be able use a for loop, e.g.

```
for f in $(ls ./00012524/*.pdf)
do
    cp $f ./dummy01
done
```

I have no way of testing this, but it should work in theory.

Comment: The ls command will probably (read "almost certainly") get the same error.  Argument too long is a standard error from the C libraries on a Unix like system (man sysconf for more on that).  The best appproaches are find ... | cpio -pvumd ... or using xargs or tar c...| tar x etc.  NOne of those will need a shell expanded glob which is the cause of his problem.  This is really more appropriate for SeverFault or SuperUser than for SO.

Comment: Improved version: `for f in ./00012524/*.pdf; do` but `find`+`xargs`+`cp -t` is much faster.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this and grab each line of the directory

```
# you can use the -rv to check the status of the command verbose

for i in /from_dir/*; do cp -rv "$i" /to_dir/; done
```