# Argument list too long error for rm, cp, mv commands

Tags: linux, unix, command-line-arguments

I have several hundred PDFs under a directory in UNIX. The names of the PDFs are really long (approx. 60 chars).

When I try to delete all PDFs together using the following command:

```
rm -f *.pdf
```

I get the following error:

```
/bin/rm: cannot execute [Argument list too long]
```

What is the solution to this error?
Does this error occur for `mv` and `cp` commands as well? If yes, how to solve for these commands?

Comment: You might find this [link](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/argument-list-too-long-error-solution/) useful

Comment: related: [Solving “mv: Argument list too long”?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128559/1321)

Comment: Also this can be relevant [http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/095](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/095)

Comment: @jww: And I continued to think for so many years that bash falls under "software tools commonly used by programmers" -- a category whose questions can be asked here!

Comment: @Nik - Adding "... in a script" is not compelling. When the problem is reduced to a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), its just a question on how to run a command. My apologies if I am missing something obvious.

Comment: @jww: not "how to run a command".. but "how to run this particular command without getting the error I was getting"... no?

Comment: Run "ulimit -S -s unlimited" command. Then perform cp/mv/rm operation.

Answer (score 1220, accepted):

The reason this occurs is because bash actually expands the asterisk to every matching file, producing a very long command line.

Try this:

```bash
find . -name "*.pdf" -print0 | xargs -0 rm
```

**Warning:** this is a recursive search and will find (and delete) files in subdirectories as well. Tack on `-f` to the rm command only if you are sure you don't want confirmation.

You can do the following to make the command non-recursive:

```bash
find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*.pdf" -print0 | xargs -0 rm
```

Another option is to use find's `-delete` flag:

```bash
find . -name "*.pdf" -delete
```

Comment: Find has a `-delete` flag to delete the files it finds, and even if it didn't it would still be considered better practice to use `-exec` to execute rm, rather than invoking xargs(which is now 3 processes and a pipe instead of a single process with `-delete` or 2 processes with `-exec`).

Comment: Only the last part of the answer is actually useful. The pipe-to-xargs suffers from basically the same problem as using globs with `rm`. But - that's not part of the original answer. It's not appropriate to edit a valid answer into an invalid one. This is a problem IMHO.

Comment: ... and the correct part was actually grafted onto this answer from a different answer which god it right. So please at least upvote that one instead.

Answer (score 580):

### tl;dr

It's a kernel limitation on the size of the command line argument. Use a `for` loop instead.

### Origin of problem

This is a system issue, related to `execve` and `ARG_MAX` constant. There is plenty of documentation about that (see [man execve](http://linux.die.net/man/2/execve), [debian's wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/CommonErrorMessages/ArgumentListTooLong), [ARG_MAX details](https://www.in-ulm.de/%7Emascheck/various/argmax/)).

Basically, the expansion produce a *command* (with its parameters) that exceeds the `ARG_MAX` limit.
On kernel `2.6.23`, the limit was set at `128 kB`. This constant has been increased and you can get its value by executing:

```bash
getconf ARG_MAX
# 2097152 # on 3.5.0-40-generic
```

### Solution: Using `for` Loop

Use a `for` loop as it's recommended on [BashFAQ/095](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/095) and there is no limit except for RAM/memory space:

Dry run to ascertain it will delete what you expect:

```bash
for f in *.pdf; do echo rm "$f"; done
```

And execute it:

```bash
for f in *.pdf; do rm "$f"; done
```

Also this is a portable approach as glob have strong and consistant behavior among shells ([part of POSIX spec](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html)).

**Note:** As noted by several comments, this is indeed slower but more maintainable as it can adapt more complex scenarios, *e.g.* where one want to do more than just one action.

### Solution: Using `find`

If you insist, you can use `find` but really **don't use xargs** as it *"is dangerous (broken, exploitable, etc.) when reading non-NUL-delimited input"*:

```bash
find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*.pdf' -delete
```

Using `-maxdepth 1 ... -delete` instead of `-exec rm {} +` allows `find` to simply execute the required system calls itself without using an external process, hence faster (thanks to [@chepner comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11289551/argument-list-too-long-error-for-rm-cp-mv-commands/18647755?noredirect=1#comment69166385_11302033)).

### References

- [I'm getting "Argument list too long". How can I process a large list in chunks?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/095) @ wooledge
- [execve(2) - Linux man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/execve) (search for ARG_MAX) ;
- [Error: Argument list too long](https://wiki.debian.org/CommonErrorMessages/ArgumentListTooLong) @ Debian's wiki ;
- [Why do I get “/bin/sh: Argument list too long” when passing quoted arguments?](https://superuser.com/questions/240183/how-to-work-around-shell-limitation-of-argument-list-too-long%29) @ SuperUser

Comment: The `find -exec` solution seems to be MUCH faster than the `for` loop.

Comment: the for loop is painfully slow.  tried this on a directory with 100,000+ files in it and 30 seconds later it had only deleted 12,000 or so.  Tried the `find` version and it was done in half a second

Comment: Five years later at 4.15.0 (`4.15.0-1019-gcp` to be exact) and the limit is still at 2097152. Interestingly enough, searching for ARG_MAX on the linux git repo gives a result showing [ARG_MAX to be at 131702.](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/6f0d349d922ba44e4348a17a78ea51b7135965b1/include/uapi/linux/limits.h)

Comment: not sure about the warning against `xargs`, from Unix Power Tools (2nd edition, O'Reilly) `find -print0 | xargs -0` is fast and will never fail.

Comment: If you're ever worried about making sure that you wrote your arguments right and the correct files will be deleted, you can replace the `find` command with `find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*.pdf' -print`. Which will show you the file list. Then if it looks fine, replace the print back with the `-delete`.

Comment: Works for multiple globs too `for for in *.pdf my_dir/*.pdf; ...`

Comment: I had about 0.5 mln fles in /tmp and `for ...` approach seems to only multiply files in this folder. `find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*.pdf' -delete` works better

Answer (score 212):

`find` has a `-delete` action:

```bash
find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*.pdf' -delete
```

Comment: This would still return "Argument list too long". At least for me it does. Using `xargs`, as per Dennis' answer, works as intended.

Comment: That sounds like a bug in find.

Comment: @Sergio had same issue, it was caused by the missing quotes around name pattern.

Comment: argh, why does a tool for finding stuff even have a switch for deleting? is it really just me who find it unnecessary to say the least and also  dangerous.

Comment: @mathreadler It addresses the fact that a common use case for `-exec` is to remove a bunch of files. `-exec rm {} +` would do the same thing, but still requires starting at least one external process. `-delete` allows `find` to simply execute the required system calls itself without using an external wrapper.

Answer (score 25):

Another answer is to force `xargs` to process the commands in batches. For instance to `delete` the files `100` at a time, `cd` into the directory and run this:

`echo *.pdf | xargs -n 100 rm`

Comment: For deleting command in linux, which can be a disaster if you are an engineer and you typed a mistake, I believe it is the 'safest and I know what's going on' is the best one. Not fancy stuff that if you miss type a dot will let your company crash down in one minute.

Comment: How can we make this the default expansion for certain commands? There's a good many "standard" linux commands where it's known if they need them all at once or not (like "rm")

Comment: Note that this only works where `echo` is a shell builtin.  If you end up using the command `echo`, you'll still run into the program arguments limit.

Comment: There is also still the inherent problem that `echo` could produce something else than the literal file names. If a file name contains a newline, it will look to `xargs` like two separate file names, and you get `rm: firsthalfbeforenewline: No such file or directory`. On some platform, file names which contain single quotes will also confuse `xargs` with the default options. (And the `-n 100` is probably way too low; just omit the option to let `xargs` figure out the optimal number of processes it needs.)

Comment: I choose `-n 100` as a conservatively low number because I don't think there is any reason to increase `n` to the point of being "optimal" here.

Answer (score 24):

If you’re trying to delete a very large number of files at one time (I deleted a directory with 485,000+ today), you will probably run into this error:

```
/bin/rm: Argument list too long.
```

The problem is that when you type something like `rm -rf *`, the `*` is replaced with a list of every matching file, like “rm -rf file1 file2 file3 file4” and so on. There is a relatively small buffer of memory allocated to storing this list of arguments and if it is filled up, the shell will not execute the program.

To get around this problem, a lot of people will use the find command to find every file and pass them one-by-one to the “rm” command like this:

```
find . -type f -exec rm -v {} \;
```

My problem is that I needed to delete 500,000 files and it was taking way too long.

I stumbled upon a much faster way of deleting files – the “find” command has a “-delete” flag built right in! Here’s what I ended up using:

```
find . -type f -delete
```

Using this method, I was deleting files at a rate of about 2000 files/second – much faster!

You can also show the filenames as you’re deleting them:

```
find . -type f -print -delete
```

…or even show how many files will be deleted, then time how long it takes to delete them:

```
root@devel# ls -1 | wc -l && time find . -type f -delete
100000
real    0m3.660s
user    0m0.036s
sys     0m0.552s
```

Comment: Thanks. I did `sudo find . -type f -delete` to delete about 485 thousand files and it worked for me. Took about 20 seconds.

Comment: I had to delete 7.4 million files. oh lord, this is the most sense answer. I love you..

Answer (score 23):

**For somone who doesn't have time.**
Run the following command on terminal.

```
ulimit -S -s unlimited
```

Then perform cp/mv/rm operation.

Comment: This doesn't work because the OP hit the /bin/rm tool's argv size limit.

Comment: Worked well for me for the error message `-bash: /bin/rm: Argument list too long`

Answer (score 15):

Or you can try:

```
find . -name '*.pdf' -exec rm -f {} \;
```

Comment: This deletes files from subdirectories as well. How to prevent that ?

Comment: @NikunjChauhan Add -maxdepth option: `find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*.pdf' -exec rm -f {} \;`

Comment: I am not able to insert the maxdepth option

Comment: That option may be a Linux-only option, as per @Dennis's answer, above (the selected answer).

Answer (score 14):

you can try this:

```bash
for f in *.pdf
do
  rm "$f"
done
```

EDIT:
ThiefMaster comment suggest me not to disclose such dangerous practice to young shell's jedis, so I'll add a more "safer" version (for the sake of preserving things when someone has a "-rf . ..pdf" file)

```bash
echo "# Whooooo" > /tmp/dummy.sh
for f in '*.pdf'
do
   echo "rm -i \"$f\""
done >> /tmp/dummy.sh
```

After running the above, just open the `/tmp/dummy.sh` file in your favorite editor and check every single line for dangerous filenames, commenting them out if found.

Then copy the `dummy.sh` script in your working dir and run it.

All this for security reasons.

Comment: I think this would do really nice things with a file named e.g. `-rf .. .pdf`

Comment: yes it would, but generally when used in shell, the issuer of the command "should" give a look at what he's doing :). Actually I prefer to redirect to a file and then inspect every single row.

Comment: This doesn't quote "$f".  That's what ThiefMaster was talking about.  `-rf` takes precedence over `-i`, so your 2nd version is no better (without manual inspection).  And is basically useless for mass delete, because of prompting for every file.

Comment: I added the missing quotes, but this still has issues. Manually inspecting thousands of files is error-prone and unnecessary.

Answer (score 12):

I'm surprised there are no `ulimit` answers here.  Every time I have this problem I end up [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128559/solving-mv-argument-list-too-long) or [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/45583/argument-list-too-long-how-do-i-deal-with-it-without-changing-my-command).  I understand this solution has limitations but `ulimit -s 65536` seems to often do the trick for me.

Answer (score 8):

You could use a bash array:

```bash
files=(*.pdf)
for((I=0;I<${#files[@]};I+=1000)); do
    rm -f "${files[@]:I:1000}"
done
```

This way it will erase in batches of 1000 files per step.

Comment: For a large number of files this seems significantly faster

Comment: This just reinvents `xargs`, rather poorly.

Answer (score 7):

If they are filenames with spaces or special characters, use:

```bash
find -name "*.pdf" -delete
```

For files in current directory only:

```bash
find -maxdepth 1 -name '*.pdf' -delete
```

This sentence search all files in the current directory (-maxdepth 1) with extension pdf (-name '*.pdf'), and then, delete.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, including an explanation of *how* and *why* this solves the problem [would really help](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: The whole point of `-exec` is that you don't invoke a shell. The quotes here do absolutely nothing useful. (They prevent any wildcard expansion and token splitting on the string *in the shell where you type in this command,* but the string `{}` doesn't contain any whitespace or shell wildcard characters.)

Comment: using `find`, but still too long

Answer (score 6):

You can use this commend

```bash
find -name "*.pdf" -delete
```

Answer (score 5):

The *rm* command has a limitation of files which you can remove simultaneous.

One possibility you can remove them using multiple times the *rm* command bases on your file patterns, like:

```
rm -f A*.pdf
rm -f B*.pdf
rm -f C*.pdf
...
rm -f *.pdf
```

You can also remove them through the *find* command:

```
find . -name "*.pdf" -exec rm {} \;
```

Comment: No, `rm` has no such limit on the number of files it will process (other than that its `argc` cannot be larger than `INT_MAX`).  It's the kernel's limitation on the maximum size of the *entire argument array* (that's why the length of the filenames is significant).

Comment: This is a very nice solution. It doesn't change the original script by much and still makes possible to delete lots of files at once. For me it worked just fine.

Answer (score 3):

And another one:

```bash
cd /path/to/pdf
printf "%s\0" *.[Pp][Dd][Ff] | xargs -0 rm
```

`printf` is a shell builtin, and as far as I know it's always been as such. Now given that `printf` is not a shell command (but a builtin), it's not subject to "`argument list too long ...`" fatal error.

So we can safely use it with shell globbing patterns such as `*.[Pp][Dd][Ff]`, then we pipe its output to remove (`rm`) command, through `xargs`, which makes sure it fits enough file names in the command line so as not to fail the `rm` command, which is a shell command.

The `\0` in `printf` serves as a null separator for the file names wich are then processed by `xargs` command, using it (`-0`) as a separator, so `rm` does not fail when there are white spaces or other special characters in the file names.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, including an explanation of *how* and *why* this solves the problem [would really help](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: In particular, if `printf` isn't a shell builtin, it will be subject to the same limitation.

Answer (score 3):

I was facing same problem while copying from source directory to destination

source directory had files ~3 lakcs

I used `cp with option -r` and it worked for me

```bash
cp -r abc/ def/
```

it will copy all files from abc to def without giving warning of *Argument list too long*

Comment: I don't know why someone downvoted this, without even commenting on that (that's policy, folks!). I needed to delete all files inside a folder (the question is not particular about PDFs, mind you), and for that, this trick is working well, all one has to do in the end is to recreate the folder that got deleted along when I used `rm -R /path/to/folder".

Comment: It works because in OP's case, he was using *, which expanded to a huge list of .pdf, giving a directory will cause this to be treated internally, thus, not having to deal with OP's issue. I think it was downvoted for that reason.
It might not be usable for OP if he have nested directory or other files (not pdf) in his directory

Answer (score 3):

Try this also If you wanna delete above 30/90 days (+) or else below 30/90(-) days files/folders then you can use the below ex commands

Ex: For 90days excludes above after 90days files/folders deletes, it means 91,92....100 days

```
find <path> -type f -mtime +90 -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Ex: For only latest 30days files that you wanna delete then use the below command (-)

```
find <path> -type f -mtime -30 -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

If you wanna giz the files for more than 2 days files

```
find <path> -type f -mtime +2 -exec gzip {} \;
```

If you wanna see the files/folders only from past one month .
Ex:

```
find <path> -type f -mtime -30 -exec ls -lrt {} \;
```

Above 30days more only then list the files/folders
Ex:

```
find <path> -type f -mtime +30 -exec ls -lrt {} \;

find /opt/app/logs -type f -mtime +30 -exec ls -lrt {} \;
```

Answer (score 3):

What about a shorter and more reliable one?

```bash
for i in **/*.pdf; do rm "$i"; done
```

Comment: Excelent approach

Answer (score 3):

### Argument list too long

As this question title for `cp`, `mv` and `rm`, but answer stand mostly for `rm`.

#### Un*x commands

Read carefully command's man page!

For `cp` and `mv`, there is a `-t` switch, for *target*:

```
find . -type f -name '*.pdf' -exec cp -ait "/path to target" {} +
```

and

```
find . -type f -name '*.pdf' -exec mv -t "/path to target" {} +
```

#### Script way

There is an overall workaroung used in [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

folder=( "/path to folder" "/path to anther folder" )

if [ "$1" != "--run" ] ;then
    exec find "${folder[@]}" -type f -name '*.pdf' -exec $0 --run {} +
    exit 0;
fi

shift

for file ;do
    printf "Doing something with '%s'.\n" "$file"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with a folder full of temporary images that was growing day by day and this command helped me to clear the folder

```
find . -name "*.png" -mtime +50 -exec rm {} \;
```

The difference with the other commands is the mtime parameter that will take only the files older than X days (in the example 50 days)

Using that multiple times, decreasing on every execution the day range, I was able to remove all the unnecessary files

Answer (score 1):

I found that for extremely large lists of files (>1e6), these answers were too slow. Here is a solution using parallel processing in python. I know, I know, this isn't linux... but nothing else here worked.

(This saved me hours)

```python
# delete files
import os as os
import glob
import multiprocessing as mp

directory = r'your/directory'
os.chdir(directory)


files_names = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format('pdf'))]

# report errors from pool

def callback_error(result):
    print('error', result)

# delete file using system command
def delete_files(file_name):
     os.system('rm -rf ' + file_name)

pool = mp.Pool(12)  
# or use pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    for file_name in files_names:
        print(file_name)
        pool.apply_async(delete_files,[file_name], error_callback=callback_error)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a temp folder, move all the files and sub-folders you want to keep into the temp folder then delete the old folder and rename the temp folder to the old folder try this example until you are confident to do it live:

```bash
mkdir testit
cd testit
mkdir big_folder tmp_folder
touch big_folder/file1.pdf
touch big_folder/file2.pdf
mv big_folder/file1,pdf tmp_folder/
rm -r big_folder
mv tmp_folder big_folder
```

the `rm -r big_folder` will remove all files in the `big_folder` no matter how many. You just have to be super careful you first have all the files/folders you want to keep, in this case it was `file1.pdf`

Comment: I actually found this page after running into file limitations for `mv` so I'm not confident this solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove both files and directories, you can use something like:

```
echo /path/* | xargs rm -rf
```

Answer (score 0):

I only know a way around this.
The idea is to export that list of pdf files you have into a file. Then split that file into several parts. Then remove pdf files listed in each part.

```
ls | grep .pdf > list.txt
wc -l list.txt
```

wc -l is to count how many line the list.txt contains. When you have the idea of how long it is, you can decide to split it in half, forth or something. Using split -l command
For example, split it in 600 lines each.

```
split -l 600 list.txt
```

this will create a few file named xaa,xab,xac and so on depends on how you split it.
Now to "import" each list in those file into command rm, use this:

```
rm $(<xaa)
rm $(<xab)
rm $(<xac)
```

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: If you have a file named `pdf_format_sucks.docx` this will be deleted as well... ;-) You should use proper and accurate regular expression when grepping for the pdf files.

Comment: Better, but `still_pdf_format_sucks.docx` will get deleted. The dot `.` in `".pdf"` regular expression matches any character. I would suggest `"[.]pdf$"` instead of `.pdf`.

Comment: But this still fails on files with irregular names, partly because of the lack of quoting. If you really feel a need to reimplement `xargs`, you need to understand all the corner cases it handles.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem a few times.  Many of the solutions will run the `rm` command for each individual file that needs to be deleted. This is very inefficient:

```sh
find . -name "*.pdf" -print0 | xargs -0 rm -rf
```

I ended up writing a python script to delete the files based on the first 4 characters in the file-name:

```python
import os
filedir = '/tmp/' #The directory you wish to run rm on 
filelist = (os.listdir(filedir)) #gets listing of all files in the specified dir
newlist = [] #Makes a blank list named newlist
for i in filelist: 
    if str((i)[:4]) not in newlist: #This makes sure that the elements are unique for newlist
        newlist.append((i)[:4]) #This takes only the first 4 charcters of the folder/filename and appends it to newlist
for i in newlist:
    if 'tmp' in i:  #If statment to look for tmp in the filename/dirname
        print ('Running command rm -rf '+str(filedir)+str(i)+'* : File Count: '+str(len(os.listdir(filedir)))) #Prints the command to be run and a total file count
        os.system('rm -rf '+str(filedir)+str(i)+'*') #Actual shell command
print ('DONE')
```

This worked very well for me. I was able to clear out over 2 million temp files in a folder in about 15 minutes. I commented the tar out of the little bit of code so anyone with minimal to no python knowledge can manipulate this code.

Comment: What's the point of a Python script if you end up shelling out with `os.system()` anyway? You want `os.unlink()` instead; then you don't have to solve the quoting problems which this fails to solve properly. But the only reason this is more efficient than `find` is that it doesn't recurse into subdirectories; you can do the same with `printf '%s\0' /tmp/* | xargs -r0 rm -rf` or of course by adding a `-maxdepth 1` option to the `find` command.

Comment: (Actually `find` will probably be quicker because the shell will alphabetize the list of files matched by the wildcard, which could be a significant amount of work when there are a lot of matches.)

Answer (score 0):

To delete all `*.pdf` in a directory `/path/to/dir_with_pdf_files/`

```bash
mkdir empty_dir        # Create temp empty dir

rsync -avh --delete --include '*.pdf' empty_dir/ /path/to/dir_with_pdf_files/
```

---

To delete specific files via `rsync` using wildcard is probably the fastest solution in case you've millions of files. And it will take care of error you're getting.

---

(Optional Step): DRY RUN. To check what will be deleted without deleting. `

```bash
rsync -avhn --delete --include '*.pdf' empty_dir/ /path/to/dir_with_pdf_files/
```

.
.
.

Click [rsync tips and tricks](https://www.quora.com/What-are-some-rsync-hacks/answer/Raman-Kathpalia?share=68335132&srid=hfE13) for more rsync hacks

Answer (score 0):

I have faced a similar problem when there were millions of useless log files created by an application which filled up all inodes. I resorted to "locate", got all the files "located"d into a text file and then removed them one by one. Took a while but did the job!

Comment: This is pretty vague and requires you to have installed `locate` back when you still had room on your disk.

Answer (score 0):

## I solved with `for`

#### I am on `macOS` with `zsh`

##### I moved thousands only `jpg` files. Within `mv` in one line command.

###### Be sure there are no spaces or special characters in the name of the files you are trying to move

```sh
for i in $(find ~/old -type f -name "*.jpg"); do mv $i ~/new; done
```

Answer (score -2):

A bit safer version than using xargs, also not recursive:

`ls -p | grep -v '/$' |  grep '\.pdf$' | while read file; do rm "$file"; done`

Filtering our directories here is a bit unnecessary as 'rm' won't delete it anyway, and it can be removed for simplicity, but why run something that will definitely return error?

Comment: This is not safe at all, and does not work with file names with newlines in them, to point out one obvious corner case.  [Parsing `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) is a common antipattern which should definitely be avoided, and adds a number of additional bugs here.  The `grep | grep` is just not very elegant.

Comment: Anyway, it's not like this is a new and exotic problem which requires a complex solution. The answers with `find` are good, and well-documented here and elsewhere.  See e.g. the http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ for much more on this and related topics.

Answer (score -2):

Using GNU parallel (`sudo apt install parallel`) is super easy

It runs the commands multithreaded where '{}' is the argument passed

E.g.

`ls /tmp/myfiles* | parallel 'rm {}'`

Comment: I don't know, but I'll guess it's because passing the output of `ls` directly to other commands is a dangerous antipattern - that, and the fact that the expansion of the wildcard will cause the same failure when executing `ls` as experienced in the original `rm` command.

Comment: For context on that, see [ParsingLs](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). And `parallel` makes some folks who prefer avoiding complexity uncomfortable -- if you look under the hood, it's pretty opaque. See the mailing list thread at https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-parallel/2015-05/msg00005.html between Stephane (one of the [Unix & Linux StackExchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) greybeards) and Ole Tange (Parallel's author). `xargs -P` also paralellizes, but it does it in a simpler, dumber way with fewer moving parts, making its behavior far easier to predict and reason about.

Answer (score -2):

To remove first 100 files:

```bash
rm -rf 'ls | head -100'
```

Comment: Dangerous (or it would be if you used backquotes as evidently intended) - if any filename contains shell metacharacters, including spaces, then the results will not be what you intended.

Answer (score -5):

The below option seems simple to this problem. I got this info from some other thread but it helped me.

```bash
for file in /usr/op/data/Software/temp/application/openpages-storage/*; do
    cp "$file" /opt/sw/op-storage/
done
```

Just run the above one command and it will do the task.