# Shell script to delete directories older than n days

Tags: bash, shell

I have directories named as:

```
2012-12-12
2012-10-12
2012-08-08
```

How would I delete the directories that are older than 10 days with a bash shell script?

Comment: To they bare any relation on their actual creation/modification  time? Because `find` could do it without looking at the name then...

Comment: they should have creation/modification time on them as well

Comment: What do you mean by "older than"?  Are you referring to the time the directory was created, the time its contents were last changed, or something else?  Be careful with some of the answers below; `ctime` is the inode change time. For a directory, it changes when files are added or removed from the directory.

Answer (score 499, accepted):

This will do it recursively for you:

```
find /path/to/base/dir/* -type d -ctime +10 -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

**Explanation:**

- `find`: the unix command for finding files / directories / links etc.
- `/path/to/base/dir`: the directory to start your search in.
- `-type d`: only find directories
- `-ctime +10`: only consider the ones with modification time older than 10 days
- `-exec ... \;`: for each such result found, do the following command in `...`
- `rm -rf {}`: recursively force remove the directory; the `{}` part is where the find result gets substituted into from the previous part.

---

**Alternatively, use:**

```
find /path/to/base/dir/* -type d -ctime +10 | xargs rm -rf
```

Which is a bit more efficient, because it amounts to:

```
rm -rf dir1 dir2 dir3 ...
```

as opposed to:

```
rm -rf dir1; rm -rf dir2; rm -rf dir3; ...
```

as in the `-exec` method.

---

With modern versions of `find`, you can replace the `;` with `+` and it will do the equivalent of the `xargs` call for you, passing as many files as will fit on each exec system call:

```
find . -type d -ctime +10 -exec rm -rf {} +
```

Comment: @bobsr See updated answer: the base directory to start your search is specified as the first argument after `find`.

Comment: `-mtime` was better for me as it checks content changes rather than permission changes, otherwise this was perfect.

Comment: @MarkReed what is the difference to put `+` instead `\` ?

Comment: @Kyrol: `+` instead of `\;` is the equivalent of: `\;`: rm -rf dir1; rm -rf dir2; rm -rf dir3; `+`: rm -rf dir1 dir2 dir3

Comment: i think this will also delete the base dir itself

Comment: I added `-prune` in my case as the original command as written recurses so the parent directory is missing.

Comment: @OrGal you are absolutely correct. In order to prevent this, just use: `find /path/to/base/dir/*`.

Comment: You need -maxdepth 1 unless you want to wait for eternity.

Comment: How about using `-delete` instead of the `-exec ...`?

Comment: you can use -maxdepth 1 to ignore contents of the directories

Comment: The more efficient approach can backfire if you have too many folders to delete: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11289551/argument-list-too-long-error-for-rm-cp-mv-commands. For the same reason, in order to avoid deletion of the base folder it's better to use `-mindepth 1` (rather than `/path/to/folder/*`).

Comment: This works but with the message: base dir 'No such file or directory'

Comment: If you do `find /path/to/base/dir/* -maxdepth 1` then you'll end up considering dirs like 'b' in /path/to/base/dir/a/b. `-maxdepth 0` doesn't work because it considers cli args only, so I think the solution is `find /path/to/base/dir -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1`

Comment: why `ctime` not `mtime` ?

Comment: In case it's helpful; to remove only sub directories with a name pattern, and are older than n days:  `find /path/to/base/dir/* -name data -type d -ctime +10 | xargs rm -rf`

Answer (score 58):

If you want to delete all subdirectories under `/path/to/base`, for example

```
/path/to/base/dir1
/path/to/base/dir2
/path/to/base/dir3
```

but you don't want to delete the root `/path/to/base`, you have to add `-mindepth 1` and `-maxdepth 1` options, which will access only the subdirectories under `/path/to/base`

`-mindepth 1` excludes the root `/path/to/base` from the matches.

`-maxdepth 1` will **ONLY** match subdirectories immediately under `/path/to/base` such as `/path/to/base/dir1`, `/path/to/base/dir2` and `/path/to/base/dir3` but it will not list subdirectories of these in a recursive manner. So these example subdirectories will not be listed:

```
/path/to/base/dir1/dir1
/path/to/base/dir2/dir1
/path/to/base/dir3/dir1
```

and so forth.

So , to delete all the sub-directories under `/path/to/base` which are older than 10 days;

```
find /path/to/base -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -ctime +10 | xargs rm -rf
```

Answer (score 32):

`find` supports `-delete` operation, so:

```
find /base/dir/* -ctime +10 -delete;
```

I think there's a catch that the files need to be 10+ days older too. Haven't tried, someone may confirm in comments.

The most voted solution here is missing `-maxdepth 0` so it will call `rm -rf` for every subdirectory, after deleting it. That doesn't make sense, so I suggest:

```
find /base/dir/* -maxdepth 0  -type d -ctime +10 -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

The `-delete` solution above doesn't use `-maxdepth 0` because `find` would complain the dir is not empty. Instead, it implies `-depth` and deletes from the bottom up.

Comment: I can confirm `-delete` works, but like you said you only can use it to delete empty directories, much like `rmdir`.

Answer (score 3):

I was struggling to get this right using the scripts provided above and some other scripts especially when files and folder names had newline or spaces.

Finally stumbled on tmpreaper and it has been worked pretty well for us so far.

```
tmpreaper -t 5d ~/Downloads


tmpreaper  --protect '*.c' -t 5h ~/my_prg
```

Original Source [link](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2013/10/tmpreaper-examples/)

Has features like test, which checks the directories recursively and lists them.
Ability to delete symlinks, files or directories and also the protection mode for a certain pattern while deleting

Answer (score 3):

OR

```
rm -rf `find /path/to/base/dir/* -type d -mtime +10`
```

Updated, faster version of it:

```
find /path/to/base/dir/* -mtime +10 -print0 | xargs -0 rm -f
```

Comment: This one could easily exceed the maximum commandline length. See `xargs --show-limits`.

Comment: Also won't work if there are filenames containing spaces or other special shell characters.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Doesn't the `-print0`/`-0` take care of the special shell characters, or no?

Comment: You're right that the `xargs` version will @mpen, but the first line won't.