# Delete Directory Older Than n Days Using Find

Tags: shell, unix

My requirements are pretty much the same as this question: [Shell script to delete directories older than n days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13868821/shell-script-delete-folders-older-than-n-days)
I've got directories that look like this:

```
Jul 24 05:46 2013_07_24

Jul 31 22:30 2013_08_01

Sep 18 05:43 2013_09_18

Oct 07 08:41 2013_10_07
```

I want to remove anything older than 90 days. Based on the solution given in the aforementioned thread, I used the following in my script:

```
find $BASE_DIR  -type d -ctime +90 -exec rm -rf  {} \;
```

The script is successfully deleting the directories, but it is also failing with this error:

```
find: 0652-081 cannot change directory to <actual_path>:
  : A file or directory in the path name does not exist.
```

The only thing here that $BASE_DIR points to a location that's virtual location and the actual_path in the error message points to the actual location. There are soft links in the environment.

Comment: Can you please post output of `find $BASE_DIR  -type d -ctime +90` ?? It seems the dir it's trying to delete has already been deleted and hence can not reference symbolic link to it.

Comment: perhaps also using the `-depth` helps?

Comment: I need to do a bit more testing, but `-depth` seems to get rid of the error. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
find $BASE_DIR -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -ctime +90 -exec rm -rf  {} \;
```

This will only cover directories directly under $BASE_DIR, but it should avoid generating that error message.

Comment: I'm sorry. I forgot to mention that I'm using Korn shell. This is the output I get: `find: 0652-017 -mindepth is not a valid option.`

Comment: I'm a little concerned that if you don't use mindepth, the entire directory might get deleted!!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
find .$BASE_DIR -type d -ctime +90 | sort -r | xargs rm -rf
```

`sort -r` will sort our directories in reverse order, so we won't try do delete external directories then internal ones.