# Find command to delete all directories under a path but not the path itself

Tags: unix, find

I want to delete all directories under my home dir but this strange doubt popped in. Will it delete my home dir as well by any chance ? Currently i am using the below oneliner.

```
find /home/chidori/ -maxdepth 1 -type d -mtime +5 -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

I was browsing through this forum and i came across this [Shell script to delete directories older than n days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13868821/shell-script-delete-folders-older-than-n-days) . The last comment says that it will delete the path mentioned in the command line as well and it urges one to use `-mindepth 1` as well.

I would like to if thats true My requirement is to delete the files under /home/chidori/ and not my home dir ( /home/chidori/) itself?

Comment: Well you can just run it without `exec` too see which directories will get effected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to delete only subdirs under specified path use:

```
find /home/chidori/ -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -mtime +5 -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

For test purpose you can echo directories that will be deleted:

```
find /home/chidori/ -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -mtime +5 -exec echo {} \;
```