# How to delete alike Apple's Time Machine?

Tags: bash, rsync

[Time Machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Machine_%28OS_X%29) saves:

- hourly backups for the past 24 hours,
- daily backups for the past month,
- weekly backups for everything older than a month until the volume runs out of space. At that point, Time Machine deletes the oldest weekly backup.

I'm at the point where I already have the bash script (`rsync`) which makes backups every hour. The backups are folders named as "`2015-01-01 08`", where "`08`" is the hour.

At some point folders older than 24h need to be deleted. So I'm looking for this magic. I guess it will be kind of `rm -R some_pattern`.

How pattern should look like?

Comment: This is off-topic because its not about development or programming. Why did you ask it here? Perhaps you should try a place like [Apple Stack Exchange](http://apple.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Sorry. Didn't know Apple Stack Exchange. Question is there now [Delete alike Apple Time Machine](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/170100/delete-alike-apple-time-machine). Thanks.

Comment: This is on topic here; it seems to be asking "how do I delete things more than a month old?". It's unlikely to be a pattern though; I think you'll want to enumerate all directories and choose which ones to delete.

Comment: `find` could be what you need, see here for a very well explained post: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13868821/shell-script-delete-folders-older-than-n-days](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13868821/shell-script-delete-folders-older-than-n-days)

Answer (score 0):

Apple Time Machine's Backups.backupdb directory contains a subfolder for each hostname, and that folder contains subfolders with names like `2017-12-21-190657`.

For that situation the shell-script below (made to trim btrfs snapshots/subvolumes equivalent Time Machine) will give you some inspiration on how to do the backup thinning/retention similar to Time Machine using bash.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Copyright © 2017, Ceriel Jacobs <http://probackup.nl/>
# Licence: GPL v3
# This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
# it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
# the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
# (at your option) any later version.
# 
# This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
# but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
# MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
# GNU General Public License for more details.
# 
# You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
# along with this program.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.

$DATE='/usr/bin/date'
$BTRFS='/usr/bin/btrfs'

pushd "$SNAPSHOT_DST/$HOST_SRC" >/dev/null
declare -a arrFiles
arrFiles=(2[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[01][0-9]-[0-3][0-9]-[0-2][0-9][0-5][0-9][0-5][0-9]) # BASH glob is auto sorted low to high
popd >/dev/null
# echo ${arrFiles[*]}

# Build epoch time array
declare -ai arrSinceEpoch
declare -i lastEpoch intTZ
# Calculate time zone correction in seconds
tmpTZ=$($DATE +%z) # f.e. +0100 -> +3600 seconds
(( intTZ = (${tmpTZ::3} * 3600) + (${tmpTZ:3:2} * 60) ))
unset tmpTZ

for c in ${!arrFiles[@]}; do
  # Replace dash between date and time by space
  # Replace dashes between time segments by colons
    # because:
    # date --date='2017-12-17-235559' +%s 
    # date: invalid date '2017-12-17-235559'
    # date --date="2017-12-17 23:55:59" +%s
    # 1513551359
  i=${arrFiles[$c]}
  strDateIn="${i::10} ${i:11:2}:${i:13:2}:${i:15:2}"
  #               -d --date   display time described by STRING, not 'now'
  #                                              %s   seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC
  strDateOut=$($DATE --date="$strDateIn" +'%F %T')
  (( arrSinceEpoch[$c]=$($DATE --date="$strDateIn" +%s) + intTZ ))
  # test sorting order
  [[ -n $lastEpoch && $lastEpoch -gt ${arrSinceEpoch[$c]} ]] && Error "Unexpected sorting order"
  lastEpoch=arrSinceEpoch[$c]
  # test date conversion
  [[ $strDateIn == $strDateOut ]] || Error "$strDateIn != $strDateOut"
done

if [[ $v='-v' ]]; then
  # First = oldest
  echo -n "Oldest backup: ${arrFiles[0]}"
  echo "  (${arrSinceEpoch[0]})"
  # Last = newest
  echo -n "Newest backup: ${arrFiles[-1]}"
  echo "  (${arrSinceEpoch[-1]})"
fi

declare -i intNewest intUpperLimit
declare -ai arrToBeRemoved
intNewest=${arrSinceEpoch[-1]}
intUpperLimitMinusSeven=$((intNewest-86400)) #24*3600 seconds
intUpperLimitMinusThirty=$((intNewest-2592000)) #30*86400 seconds

# Retention Rules
# - don't touch newest 24h versions
# - from old to new, keep only 1st version per day until newest-24 hours is reached
# - from old to new, keep oldest backup, and store versions that are at least 7 days newer as the previous
#   until newest-30 days is reached

# 1/2 Thinning to 1 version per day
lastday=''
for c in ${!arrFiles[@]}; do
  if [[ ${arrSinceEpoch[$c]} -gt $intUpperLimitMinusSeven ]]; then
    [[ $v='-v' ]] && echo "<24h: ${arrFiles[$c]}, [$c]"
    break # exit for loop because all (remaining) backups are made within 24 hours of the "latest" backup
  elif [[ -n $lastday && $lastday == ${arrFiles[$c]::10} ]]; then
     # duplicate day found -> add this snapshot to the to-be-removed array
     [[ $v='-v' ]] && echo "Remove snapshot: ${arrFiles[$c]}, [$c]"
     arrToBeRemoved[$c]=1
  fi
  lastday=${arrFiles[$c]::10}
done

# 2/3 Thinning to 1 version per week
# fulldate to day: 2017-12-21-164100 -> 1513541787 -> /86400 -> day# 17517
# save snap when snap day >= last week snap day + 7 days
# TODO: improve to allow some rounding: f.e. not delete #6 in 1,6,14,21
declare -i idxLastSavedWeekSnap intLastSavedWeekSnapDay intTemp
idxLastSavedWeekSnap=0
intLastSavedWeekSnapDay=$((${arrSinceEpoch[0]}/86400)) # epoch seconds to day number

for c in ${!arrFiles[@]}; do
  if [[ ${arrSinceEpoch[$c]} -gt $intUpperLimitMinusThirty ]]; then
    [[ $v='-v' ]] && echo "<30d: ${arrFiles[$c]}, [$c]"
    break # exit for loop because all (remaining) backups are made within 30 days of the "latest" backup
  elif [[ $c = 0 ]]; then
    continue # skip this snap, always keep 1st snapshot
  elif [[ ${arrToBeRemoved[$c]} = 1 ]]; then
    continue # skip this snap, already marked for deletion
  else
    intTemp=${arrSinceEpoch[$c]}/86400
    if [[ $intTemp -ge $intLastSavedWeekSnapDay ]]; then
      intLastSavedWeekSnapDay=$intTemp
    else
      arrToBeRemoved[$c]=1
    fi
  fi 
done

# print array count & indexes
if [[ $v='-v' && -n ${!arrToBeRemoved[@]} ]]; then
  echo -n "To be removed (${#arrToBeRemoved[@]}): "
  printf '#%s ' "${!arrToBeRemoved[@]}"
  echo
fi

# 3/3 If there are items to-be-removed
if [[ -n ${!arrToBeRemoved[@]} ]]; then
  # delete corresponding snapshots
  for c in ${!arrToBeRemoved[@]}; do
    [[ $v='-v' ]] && echo -n "btrfs subvolume delete $SNAPSHOT_DST/$HOST_SRC/${arrFiles[$c]};"
    #$BTRFS subvolume delete $SNAPSHOT_DST/$HOST_SRC/${arrFiles[$c]}
  done
  [[ $v='-v' ]] && echo
fi
```

Comment: `let` (as well as `expr`) are a bit antiquated. POSIX `((...))` should be used for arithmetic (and numeric comparison).

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thanks for the tip regarding `let`, they have been changed 2x to `((...))` with the bonus of not doing any word splitting according to https://ss64.com/bash/let.html (more coding suggestions are welcome)

Comment: Well, you are showing great effort, but it may be worth another look at how to handle POSIX arithmetic. For assignment and immediate use it is `var=$((math stuff))`, for increment or decrement, you can use `((n++))`, and for comparison it is `if ((math comparison)); then ...` I edited the math for you. See [Arithmetic Expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_04)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin The ((var=...)) arithmetic is fault free: `((i=3*4));echo $i
12`. And `let` is not deprecated though includes potential word splitting issues. Here I see the benefit of the change. Your proposed `var=$((...))` is no longer a compound command but substitution. POSIX is not the environment of this question, BASH is. For edit #4 I don't see any benefit in the context of this question.

Comment: I'm not being critical, and I did not say `let` was deprecated. The assignment within works, but can be visually ambiguous to `((i==3*4))`, while bash is the intepreter, POSIX provides the arithmetic, intentionally so. You can always revert my edit by clicking on `edit` and restoring your prior version.

Answer (score 0):

This is the easiest solution using OSX Terminal.

Get a list of all the backups in TimeMachine. This will also show you the full directory path to the backups that you will need in step 2...

> $ tmutil listbackups

```
/Volumes/Time Machine Backups/Backups.backupdb/{your-macbook}/2018-10-02-213405
/Volumes/Time Machine Backups/Backups.backupdb/{your-macbook}/2018-10-09-192323
/Volumes/Time Machine Backups/Backups.backupdb/{your-macbook}/2018-10-19-212659
```

Choose which backups to delete based on their date. Note the use of a wildcard * and the use of the directory from step 1. For example, to delete all of 2018's backups you would use this:

> $sudo tmutil delete '/Volumes/Time Machine
>   Backups/Backups.backupdb/{your-macbook}/2018-'*

The final step is to shrink and recover space from the sparse bundle. Search your backup drive for the .sparsebundle file.

> $ sudo hdiutil compact '/Volumes/{your-mac}.sparsebundle'