# function to delete folders older than 10 days in vb

Tags: vb.net, io

I want to create a function which should delete all subfolders of a folder which are 10 days older.

[Shell script to delete directories older than n days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13868821/shell-script-delete-folders-older-than-n-days)

I want show all the folder and count how much old and delete if it is 10 days old.

```
enter code here
Private Function test(ByVal directory As String) As String()
Dim fi As New IO.DirectoryInfo(directory)
Dim path() As String = {}
For Each subfolder As IO.DirectoryInfo In fi.GetDirectories()
 Array.Resize(path, path.Length + 1)
 path(path.Length - 1) = subfolder.FullName
 For Each s As String In test(subfolder.FullName)
 Array.Resize(path, path.Length + 1)
 path(path.Length - 1) = s
 Dim w = IO.Path.GetFileName(s)
 '' ListBox1.Items.Add(w)
 Dim iDate As String = w
 Dim oDate As DateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(iDate)
 ''MsgBox(oDate.Day & " " & oDate.Month & "  " & oDate.Year)
 DateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.Today
 Dim date2 As Date = oDate
 Dim span = DateTimePicker1.Value - date2
 Dim days As Double = span.TotalDays
 '' MsgBox(days)
 '' ListBox1.Items.Add(days)
    Next
   Next
```

this part is not working

```
  If days > 10 Then
   fi.Delete()
  End If
```

Comment: Without reviewing the whole code, but why do you think that `If days < 10` deletes folders that are olders than 10 days? Should it be `> 10`?

Comment: Apart from that(now fixed), why do you use `IO.Path.GetFileName` to get the `Date`? You could use `Directory.GetCreationTime(path)` or `DirectoryInfo.CreationTime`.

Comment: to get the file name .which are in format of "mm/dd/yyyy"

Comment: i have find difference between today's date and File name  date

Comment: Have you used the debugger? What happened, what was wrong, what value had `oDate`, what value had `DateTimePicker1.Value`? Maybe months and days were swapped, like `02/03/2015` which could mean march in germany but february in USA. Note that `/` will be replaced by the actual localized date separators of your current culture.

Comment: that folder are created by compuer/mechine

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79540/discussion-between-tom-and-tim-schmelter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate through the directory, get each folder's properties, and get the `TimeSpan` difference from today to the folder's creation date.

```
Try
    Dim dtCreated As DateTime
    Dim dtToday As DateTime = Today.Date
    Dim diObj As DirectoryInfo
    Dim ts As TimeSpan
    Dim lstDirsToDelete As New List(Of String)

    For Each sSubDir As String In Directory.GetDirectories(sDirectory)
        diObj = New DirectoryInfo(sSubDir)
        dtCreated = diObj.CreationTime

        ts = dtToday - dtCreated

        'Add whatever storing you want here for all folders...

        If ts.Days > 10 Then
            lstDirsToDelete.Add(sSubDir)
            'Store whatever values you want here... like how old the folder is
            diObj.Delete(True) 'True for recursive deleting
        End If
    Next
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error Deleting Folder", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
End Try
```

Comment: You may consider using `LastWriteTimeUtc`.  UTC will eliminate issues with timezone and daylight savings settings, while unlike `CreationTime`,`LastWrite` will change with edits thus providing a more accurate date.