# find and delete file or folder older than x days

Tags: linux, shell, automation

I want to delete file and folder older than 7 days so I tried

```
[17:07:14 root@client01.abc.com:~]# find /tmp/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -ctime +7 -exec ls -l {} \;
```

So when I run `find /tmp/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -ctime +7 -exec ls -l {} \;` it doesnt show any dir, but for `find /tmp/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 2 -ctime +7 -exec ls -l {} \;` it does show few files in subdir.

Whats is the right way to delete files/folders older than 7 days in one specific dir ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Shell script to delete directories older than n days](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13868821/608639)

Comment: Do you want to delete directories *and* files with a single find command, or are you ok with two separate commands?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

You can make use of this piece of code

```
find /tmp/* -mtime +7 -exec rm {} \;
```

**Explanation**

- The first argument is the path to the files. This can be a path, a directory, or a wildcard as in the example above. I would recommend using the full path, and make sure that you run the command without the exec rm to make sure you are getting the right results.
- The second argument, `-mtime`, is used to specify the number of days old that the file is. If you enter `+7`, it will find files older than 7 days.
- The third argument, `-exec`, allows you to pass in a command such as rm. The `{} \;` at the end is required to end the command.

Source : http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/delete-files-older-than-x-days-on-linux/

For deleting folders, after emptying inside of them you can `rmdir`instad of `rm` in the piece of code, also if you only want to see directories you can add

```
-type d
```

to piece of code such as below:

```
find /tmp/*/* -mtime +7 -type d -exec rmdir {} \;
```

Comment: is it going to delete dir inside /tmp/ older than +7 days too ?

Comment: I'm editing for removing directory info too, check the bottom @roy

Comment: I'm going to say it. Find is the most terrifying & dangerous command I ever run. A misplaced order of operations, a lack of quotes in the execute string, a simple logic error? And you can end up deleting or modifying a whole host of items you didn't expect. And it doesn't help if you run it without an -exec first, because the unquoted items aren't being passed to a command. I highly recommend running it through '-exec ls {} \;' first to make sure that you aren't getting strange separations due to white space or other characters causing your * to target a whole slew of things you didn't expect.

Comment: I I think this is the best way to achieve what was asked from Roy.
This because in first you are thinking to deleted files, then you safely can remove empty directories.
For this purpose you can simply use this command:
find /tmp/ -type d -empty -delete

Comment: Probably do a dry run first by leaving off the "-exec rmdir () \;" - just to be safe

Answer (score 18):

Easier to just do

```
find /tmp/* -mtime +7 -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Which will del files and dirs

Comment: Your command works, but it delete all files and folders, even if not empty.

Answer (score 7):

my easy way:

```
find /tmp/* -daystart -mtime +7 -delete
```

the `daystart` option measure times from the beginning of today rather than from 24 hours ago

ref: [official_doc](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/find.html)

Answer (score 5):

```
find /tmp/* -mtime +7 -type f -exec rm {} \;
```

Remove files.

```
find /tmp/ -empty -type d -delete
```

Remove empty directories.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend this oneliner to delete all old files within 8 days:

```
find /tmp/ -mtime +8 -type f -exec rm {} \; -o \
  -mtime +8 -type d -empty -exec rmdir {} \;
```

The `-o` splits the files and directories so that we don't delete the directories and then get an error because the files doesn't exist anymore. It will also delete old files in a directory with newer files.

This may result in empty directories staying 8 more days since deletion of a files updates the directory.