# Delete old files using ls and find command

Tags: linux, bash, shell

My folder structer looks like below:

```
folder1
        ---tmp
        ---sub1
folder2
        ---tmp
        ---sub2
folder3
        ---tmp
        ---sub3
folder4
        ---tmp
        ---sub4
```

I want to delete files which older than 30 days in all tmp folder.

## list all tmp folder:

```
ls -d */tmp
```

## delete all files which older than 30 days

```
find . -mtime +30 -type f -delete
```

Could i combine these 2 steps into one command line?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [find and delete file or folder older than x days](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31389483/608639), [Delete files older than 10 days using shell script in Unix](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13489398/608639), etc.

Comment: @jww clearly the OP knows how to do this. What he was wondering about is how to restrict the file-selection to particular subdirectories with a well-known name. Are your suggestions related? Yes! Duplicates? Debatable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do is replace the `.` in your find with the actual directories you want to search in.

```
find */tmp -mtime +30 -type f -delete
```

If `tmp` can be several levels deeper then you might be interested in

```
find . -regex '.*/tmp/[^/]+' -mtime +30 -type f -delete
```

or similar to the first option, but by using the double-star globular expression (enabled with `shopt -s globstar`)

```
find **/tmp -mtime +30 -type f -delete
```

> **`*`** Matches any string, including the null string.  When the globstar shell option is enabled, and `*` is used in a pathname expansion context, two adjacent `*`s used as a single pattern will match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.  If followed by a `/`, two adjacent `*`s will match only directories and subdirectories.
>
> **<sup>source: `man bash`</sup>**

**Note:** you have to be careful though. Imagine that you have a directory `folder1/tmp/foo/` then the above commands (with exception of the regex version) will select also files in `folder1/tmp/foo` and this might not be wanted. You might be interested in the extra option `-maxdepth 1`

Comment: @jww also I do not have a problem with downvoting. But I would appreciate it if you add some information. If it goes against the rules of how Stack Overflow works, point me to the rules and I will follow. If you have a problem with this answer because of a given logic which I overlooked. Then explain to me what the problem is. We are all here to learn and share. (ps I know [commenting is not needed with downvoting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357436/), I'm just curious why)