# linux command to delete a pattern of files on a specific date range

Tags: linux, datetime, delete-file

I have set of log files which I need to delete every week.
I want to know how to delete specific set of log files which are two days older to current date

eg:

```
-rw-r----- 1 admin admin  4367 Oct 15 02:23 server-129.log
-rw-r----- 1 admin admin  4218 Oct 16 05:47 server-130.log
-rw-r----- 1 admin admin  3370 Oct 16 09:10 server-131.log
-rw-r----- 1 admin admin  2742 Oct 17 12:33 server-132.log
-rw-r----- 1 admin admin  3726 Oct 17 15:57 server-133.log
-rw-r----- 1 admin admin  2660 Oct 17 19:20 server-134.log
-rw-r----- 1 admin admin  5223 Oct 18 22:44 server-135.log
-rw-r----- 1 admin admin  4212 Oct 19 12:07 server-136.log
-rw-r----- 1 admin admin  2501 Oct 19 15:29 server-137.log
```

I want to delete specifically server logs before 18th.

Comment: try a find command..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Shell script delete folders older than n days](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13868821/shell-script-delete-folders-older-than-n-days)

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
find -mtime 2 | xargs rm
```

This would find all files modified 2*24h=48h ago. This result can be piped to the rm command.