# Automatically delete old Python log files

Tags: python, logging

I have a Python program that runs daily. I'm using the `logging` module with FileHandler to write logs to a file. I would like each run's logs to be in its own file with a timestamp. However, I want to delete old files (say > 3 months) to avoid filling the disk.

I've looked at the RotatingFileHandler and TimedRotatingFileHandler but I don't want a single run's logs to be split across multiple files, even if a single run were to take days. Is there a built-in method for that?

Comment: You could do this outside Python, just use a Cron job to run `find` (see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/13869000/3001761) every so often. But I'm confused by *"I would like each day's logs to be in their own file"* vs. *"I don't want a single run's logs to be split across multiple files, even if a single run were to take days"*.

Comment: Thanks. I'm looking for a solution within the logging module, though. I've edited for clarity.

Comment: @jonrsharpe cron got deprecated a long time ago and hasn't worked well in osx for many tasks.

Answer (score 15):

The logging module has a built in TimedRotatingFileHandler:

```
# import module
from logging.handlers import TimedRotatingFileHandler
from logging import Formatter

# get named logger
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

# create handler
handler = TimedRotatingFileHandler(filename='runtime.log', when='D', interval=1, backupCount=90, encoding='utf-8', delay=False)

# create formatter and add to handler
formatter = Formatter(fmt='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
handler.setFormatter(formatter)

# add the handler to named logger
logger.addHandler(handler)

# set the logging level
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

# --------------------------------------

# log something
logger.info("test")
```

Old logs automatically get a timestamp appended.

Every day a new backup will be created.

If more than 91 (current+backups) files exist the oldest will be deleted.

Answer (score 4):

```
import logging
import time
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler

logFile = 'test-' + time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")+ '.log'

logger = logging.getLogger('my_logger')
handler = RotatingFileHandler(logFile, mode='a', maxBytes=50*1024*1024, 
                                 backupCount=5, encoding=None, delay=False)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.addHandler(handler)

for _ in range(10000):
    logger.debug("Hello, world!")
```

Answer (score 2):

As suggest by @MartijnPieters in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55170348/why-timedrotatingfilehandler-does-not-delete-old-files), you could easily extend the FileHandler class in order to handle your own deletion logic. 
For example, my class will hold only the last "backup_count" files.

```
import os
import re
import datetime
import logging 
from itertools import islice


class TimedPatternFileHandler(logging.FileHandler):
    """File handler that uses the current time fo the log filename,
    by formating the current datetime, according to filename_pattern, using
    the strftime function.

    If backup_count is non-zero, then older filenames that match the base
    filename are deleted to only leave the backup_count most recent copies,
    whenever opening a new log file with a different name.

    """

    def __init__(self, filename_pattern, mode, backup_count):
        self.filename_pattern = os.path.abspath(filename_pattern)
        self.backup_count = backup_count
        self.filename = datetime.datetime.now().strftime(self.filename_pattern)


        delete = islice(self._matching_files(), self.backup_count, None)
        for entry in delete:
            # print(entry.path)
            os.remove(entry.path)
        super().__init__(filename=self.filename, mode=mode)

    @property
    def filename(self):
        """Generate the 'current' filename to open"""
        # use the start of *this* interval, not the next
        return datetime.datetime.now().strftime(self.filename_pattern)

    @filename.setter
    def filename(self, _):
        pass

    def _matching_files(self):
        """Generate DirEntry entries that match the filename pattern.

        The files are ordered by their last modification time, most recent
        files first.

        """
        matches = []
        basename = os.path.basename(self.filename_pattern)
        pattern = re.compile(re.sub('%[a-zA-z]', '.*', basename))

        for entry in os.scandir(os.path.dirname(self.filename_pattern)):
            if not entry.is_file():
                continue
            entry_basename = os.path.basename(entry.path)
            if re.match(pattern, entry_basename):
                matches.append(entry)
        matches.sort(key=lambda e: e.stat().st_mtime, reverse=True)
        return iter(matches)


def create_timed_rotating_log(path):
    """"""
    logger = logging.getLogger("Rotating Log")
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

    handler = TimedPatternFileHandler('{}_%H-%M-%S.log'.format(path), mode='a', backup_count=5)

    logger.addHandler(handler)
    logger.info("This is a test!")
```

Answer (score -1):

Get the date/time. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237079/how-to-get-file-creation-modification-date-times-in-python) on how to get the timestamp. If the file is older than the current date by 3 months. Then delete it with

```
import os
os.remove("filename.extension")
```

save this file to [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/), then just use any task scheduler to run this job at startup.

**Windows**: open the **run** command and enter **shell:startup**, then place your exe in here.

**On OSX**: The old way used to be to create a cron job, this doesn't work in many cases from my experience anymore but still work trying. The new recommended way by apple is [CreatingLaunchdJobs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html). You can also refer to this [topic](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/156288/how-to-get-shell-scripts-to-run-at-startup-on-yosemite) for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but the question is about where the logging module itself supports this kind of functionality. Creating a separate program to handle it is straightforward enough.