# Shell script to remove backups that are older than 2 Weeks

Tags: shell, ubuntu, scripting, cron

I have a shell script that takes the backup of the Mongo DB on a daily basis. It's working as expected. Now I need to remove the backups that are older than 2 weeks. Would that be achievable with the current naming convention. Can anyone shed some light? I'm fairly new to shell scripting

```
#!/bin/sh
DIR=`date +%m%d%y`
DEST=/dbBackups/$DIR
mkdir $DEST
mongodump --authenticationDatabase admin -h 127.0.0.1 -d pipe -u <username> -p <password>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13868821/shell-script-to-delete-directories-older-than-n-days

Comment: In that case would this do for me find /dbBackups/* -type d -ctime +14 -exec rm -rf {} \;

Answer (score 1):

Finally got it with the below script

```
#!/bin/sh
DIR=`date +%m%d%y`
DEST=/dbBackups/$DIR
mkdir $DEST
mongodump --authenticationDatabase admin -h 127.0.0.1 -d pipe -u <username> -p <password>
find /dbBackups/* -type d -ctime +14 -exec rm -rf {} +
```

Thanks to [Shell script to delete directories older than n days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13868821/shell-script-to-delete-directories-older-than-n-days)

Comment: With GNU find, running `-exec rm -rf {} +` will be faster as it won't spawn a separate process for each file.

Comment: Just a note for people using code in this answer, I think you'll likely want "-o $DEST" at the end of the mongodump line eg
mongodump --authenticationDatabase admin -h 127.0.0.1 -d pipe -u <username> -p <password> -o $DEST