# How to write a shell script to delete the logs with PII data if it's older than 15 days

Tags: shell

Can someone let me know how to write a shell script to delete the logs with PII data if it's older than 15 days

Comment: `with PII data` What are "PII data"?

Comment: Is this a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13868821/shell-script-to-delete-directories-older-than-n-days ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Shell script to delete directories older than n days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13868821/shell-script-to-delete-directories-older-than-n-days)

Comment: PII Data is nothing but personally identifiable information like username, password, telephone number etc