# List files matching pattern when too many for bash globbing

Tags: bash, find, ls

I'd like to run the following:

```
ls /path/to/files/pattern*
```

and get

```
/path/to/files/pattern1 
/path/to/files/pattern2 
/path/to/files/pattern3
```

However, there are too many files matching the pattern in that directory, and I get

```
bash: /bin/ls: Argument list too long
```

What's a better way to do this?  Maybe using the find command? I need to print out the full paths to the files.

Comment: Have you tried `find /path/to/files -name 'pattern*'`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Argument list too long error for rm, cp, mv commands](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11289551/argument-list-too-long-error-for-rm-cp-mv-commands)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

This is where `find` in combination with `xargs` will help.

```
find /path/to/files -name "pattern*" -print0 | xargs -0 ls
```

**Note from comments:** `xargs` will help if you wish to do with the list once you have obtained it from `find`. If you only intend to list the files, then `find` should suffice. However, if you wish to `copy`, `delete` or perform any action on the list, then using `xargs` instead of `-exec` will help.

Comment: Actually, find /path/to/files -name "pattern*" seems to do exactly what I want -- any reason not to use that?  Thanks!

Comment: Well only if you wish to do something once you have obtained a list. For example copy them somewhere else, or delete them. In such cases `xargs` will help. If you just want to list them, then yes, you don't need `xargs` for that.

Comment: Great -- I'm actually using this command to pipe into GNU parallel, which I use instead of xargs.  [No need for the -print0 in that case.]

Comment: Worked... I used a slightly different version: `find / -name "pattern*" 2>/dev/null -print0 | xargs -0 ls -la` ... the devnull stuff suppresses permissions errors.