# Multiple greps with specific number taken from an array size

Tags: bash

I am writing a script that searches for various strings in various folders .
I need to run multiple greps for the strings in the order they appear in the array .

The variable reading from the array is : `${STRINGS_2_SEARCH[$j]`

It should be something like this in a loop :

```
find ${FOLDERS_2_SEARCH[$i]} -type f -name "*.*" | \ 
   xargs zegrep -i ${STRINGS_2_SEARCH[1]  | \
   xargs zegrep -i ${STRINGS_2_SEARCH[2] ....... | \
   xargs zegrep -i ${STRINGS_2_SEARCH[n]
```

The `| xargs zegrep -i ${STRINGS_2_SEARCH[j]` need to be substituted according to the number of strings to serch I added to the array .

Regards
   Raz

Comment: You could probably condense this into a single command. `find` accepts multiple paths to search and the regexes could trivially be merged into a single regex. If output order is important, postprocessing might be more efficient than running multiple `find`s.

Answer (score 0):

another soloution could be to use awk for search. You would avoid multiple invocations of grep.

first step: build an awk search pattern from your array.

```
for px in "${STRINGS_2_SEARCH[@]}"
do
  patt="$patt;/$xx/"
done
awkpattern=${patt:1}
```

second step: pipe your output of find in a loop for searching

```
find .... | while read pth
do
  echo $pth | awk "$awkpattern"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of multiple greps, create a single pattern by concatenating all your search strings and then use a single grep as shown below:

```
STRINGS_2_SEARCH=(foo bar baz)
PATTERN=$(IFS='|'; echo "${STRINGS_2_SEARCH[*]}")

find ${FOLDERS_2_SEARCH[$i]} -type f -name "*.*" | xargs zegrep -i "$PATTERN"
```

---

Alternatively, write another script called `mygrep.sh` and write a loop to grep for each pattern on a single file:

```
#!/bin/bash
# mygrep.sh
STRINGS_2_SEARCH=(foo bar baz)
FILE="$1"
for i in "${STRINGS_2_SEARCH[@]}"
do
    zegrep -i "${STRINGS_2_SEARCH[i]" "$FILE"
done
```

Then run:

```
find ${FOLDERS_2_SEARCH[$i]} -type f -name "*.*" -exec mygrep.sh {} \;
```

Comment: Why not use `-exec` on your first example also instead of piping?

Comment: `xargs` is more efficient than `find ... -exec` for large numbers of files because it won't create a new child grep process for each file.

Comment: But wouldn't piping cause problems if there are spaces in the filenames/paths?

Comment: if filenames could have newlines/spaces etc then you must use `find ... -print0 | xargs -0...` to use null-delimited filenames instead.

Answer (score 0):

### You don't need `find`, only `grep`

```
shopt -s globstar
pattern=( -e 'example' -e 'multiple' -e 'on' )
files=( *.html *.log **/*.txt ); 
grep "${pattern[@]}" "${files[@]}"
```

#### Explanation

1. `globstar`: allow recursive exploration
2. `pattern`: store patterns in an array (also increase readibility in script)
3. `files`: store files to grep in an array, then expand with `${files[@]}`

> -e PATTERN, --regexp=PATTERN
>
> ```
>   Use PATTERN as the pattern.  This can be used to specify multiple 
>   search patterns, or to protect a pattern beginning with a
>   hyphen (-).  (-e is specified by POSIX.)
> ```

#### References

- Be aware of [`xargs` issue when using it with `find`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind?highlight=%28xargs%29#Actions_in_bulk%3a_xargs.2C_-print0_and_-exec_.2B-)
- globstar: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/internals/shell_options#globstar

Comment: this won't work if you have a large number of files. You will get an "argument list too long" error.

Comment: The issue is not about the number of files, but the length of the expanded command. Moreover the `ARG_MAX` value is pretty high nowadays (> 2M): http://stackoverflow.com/a/18647755/802365

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that makes use of `awk` to parse the list of strings that you are searching for into a regular expression that will match all of them. I.e. `"foo bar"` becomes `"foo|bar"`. We then feed this string into `grep`. I have added the `-Hn` flags to `grep` which will display file name and line number along with `grep` results which could make parsing the results easier, depending on your use case. Finally `grep` is being called on each file that `find` locates via the `-exec` flag.

```
find ${FOLDERS_2_SEARCH[$i]} -type f -name "*.*" \
-exec egrep -Hn \
"$( awk '{for(i=1;i<NF;i++) { printf($i"|") }; printf($NF); printf("\n") }' \
<( echo ${STRINGS_2_SEARCH[$j]} ) )" {} \;
```