# Unzip: how to pass error?

Tags: shell, terminal, unzip

Given a script generating 100 .zip files, of which some are empty. (Even if there is nothing to zip, my script generate 100 .zip files).

Given the command :

```
unzip *.zip
```

I get an error on empty files :

```
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of ./data/Archive_03.zip or
        ./data/Archive_03.zip.zip, and cannot find ./data/Archive_03.zip.ZIP, period.
```

**How can I bypass these fake .zip files and silent this `unzip` error ?**

Comment: You can hide errors with `unzip *.zip 2>/dev/null`, but don't know if it suffices to you.

Comment: Nope. Still crashing.

Comment: Not programming related. Try SuperUser.

Comment: The core of your problem is that, by default, `unzip` interprets only the first parameter (e.g. `Archive_01.zip`) to refer to an archive. Any subsequent parameter (e.g. `Archive_02.zip`, `Archive_03.zip` etc.) is interpreted to refer to a file *inside* `Archive_01.zip` that should be extracted from it. The answers show you how to avoid the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Core solution

Using `bash`, you can just loop over the zip files instead of using a glob. This allows to prevent the [Argument list too long error for rm, cp, mv commands](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18647755/802365) and continue even if one file fail.

```
dir="/path/to/zip-dir"
cd "$dir"

for zf in *.zip
do
  unzip "$zf"
done
```

### Testing before doing

You can add an extra test, in the `for` loop, to check if the *file exists and has a size greater than zero* before unzipping:

```
if [[ -s "$zf" ]];
then
  unzip "$zf" # greater exist & size>0
else
  printf "file doesn't exists or null-size: %s\n" "$zf"
fi
```

a shorter version will be: `[[ -s "$zf" ]] && unzip "$zf"` (unzip only if exists and >0).

### Reference

- see `man bash` (look for `-s` or `CONDITIONAL EXPRESSIONS` section).
- Question [Argument list too long error for rm, cp, mv commands](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11289551/802365)

Answer (score 1):

Option 1: use it with care - http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/unzip/

```
unzip -fo *.zip
```

Option 2: This may not work, it works for .gz extension.

```
tar -zxvf test123.tar.gz

z -- unzip
x -- extract the file
v -- verbose
f -- forcefully done
```