# How to combine thousands of .csv files into one master file?

Tags: csv

I have a folder of a little over 10,000 `.csv` files that I want to combine into one master file. They are all categorized the same way (Column A B C D E F are the same thing in each file). I'd prefer to do it in a shell script.

I tried

```
cat *.csv > Everything.csv
```

and it returns that Argument is too long

I also tried

```
copy *.csv > Everything.csv
```

and it returns the same error.

How do I get it to combine about 10,000 files into one Master file?

Answer (score 1):

This question discusses the error you're seeing: [Argument list too long error for rm, cp, mv commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11289551/argument-list-too-long-error-for-rm-cp-mv-commands)

One possible solution would be something like:

```
find . -name "*.csv" -exec cat '{}' >> ./Everything.csv ';'
```

Comment: I used a more powerful computer. It returned the error "input file is output file."

Comment: Try calling the output file "Everything.output" then renaming to .csv?

Answer (score 0):

I've done it using:

```
cat *.csv >> /tmp/master_file_name.csv
```

Single '>' will re-write the file, not append it,

Comment: returns error

-bash: /bin/cat: Argument list too long

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple for loop:

```
for file in `ls`; do
    cat $file >> master_file
done
```

Answer (score 0):

`find . -name "*.csv" | xargs -I{} cat '{}' > Everything.csv`

(edit) Ah well, beat to the punch...

Comment: Returns error "cat: ./Everything.csv: input file is output file"

Comment: True, and everything is in the Everything.csv when done (i.e., you still get the right answer).  It's a warning, really.  If your output file didn't end in .csv, or if it were in a different directory above the current one, you would not get that warning.