# Argument Too Long - Using RM and Wildcard

Tags: linux, unix, cpanel

I want to empty a folder called 'cur' across **all** accounts on my server. Which is setup with this format. I want cur to remain.

```
/home/ACCNAME/mail/cur/*
```

After trying to empty a single folder manually using

```
rm -f /home/ACCNAME/mail/cur/*
```

and being presented with 'Argument too long. I can be sure I cannot run this using wildcards across all accounts.

How would I do this process, if I wanted to use wildcard to repeat this process across all accounts

like this (but without Argument too long error)

```
rm -f /home/*/mail/cur*
```

Would something like that work?

Or does the first asterisk match everything after it, so in essence it would remove the entire home folder.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Argument list too long error for rm, cp, mv commands](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11289551/argument-list-too-long-error-for-rm-cp-mv-commands)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use xargs and find:

```
for x in /home/*/mail/cur/
do
    find $x -type f 2>/dev/null | xargs rm -f 
done
```

Comment: Since this is Linux and will have GNU `find` and `xargs`, you might prefer to use `-print0` with `find` and `-0` with `xargs`.  Or you could avoid `xargs` altogether with `find "$x" -type f -exec rm -f {} +` or even `find "$x" -type f -delete`.  All three mechanisms will handle any arbitrary file names.