# Can't install ejabberd on Mac

Tags: linux, macos, xmpp, ejabberd

I am trying to install ejabberd server in my own mac by following the official [instruction](http://docs.ejabberd.im/developer/install-osx/). However, when I run `make && make install`, it gives me weird error messages.  I did search on stackoverflow and found `Argument list too long` is a error because of long input -- [See link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11289551/argument-list-too-long-error-for-rm-cp-mv-commands). However, I never changed any code in ejabberd and it is original cloned from github [official repository](https://github.com/processone/ejabberd).

My OS is Mac OS X El Captain 10.11.1.

Any ideas? How can I get rid of the `Argument List too long` error?

```
checking openssl/sha.h presence... yes
checking for openssl/sha.h... yes
configure: creating ./config.status
./config.status: line 268: /usr/bin/sed: Argument list too long
./config.status: line 275: /bin/rm: Argument list too long
./config.status: line 279: /bin/rm: Argument list too long
./config.status: line 299: /bin/rm: Argument list too long
./config.status: line 393: /usr/bin/sed: Argument list too long
./config.status: line 509: /usr/bin/sed: Argument list too long
./config.status: line 558: /bin/mkdir: Argument list too long
: error: cannot create a temporary directory in .
ERROR: Command ['get-deps'] failed!
make: *** [deps/.got] Error 1
```

Comment: Any ideas!! Please!!

Answer (score 0):

The standard installation document explains what need to be done with latest OSX:
http://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/guide/installation/#specific-notes-for-osx-yosemite-or-el-capitan

You need to define the path to libraries installed by homebrew (expat and openssl).

We will also update the developer page to reflect the specific need of latest OSX versions.