# Getting "argument list too long" error

Tags: unix, grep

Trying to get a string from a location which has lots of file. Getting error as `argument list too long`, have tired `xargs` but there's no support for these advanced keywords

```
grep 'hello' /file/collection/*/logs/*.log > ~/hello
```

Comment: Related: [Does "argument list too long"
 apply to shell builtins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47443380/does-argument-list-too-long-restriction-apply-to-shell-builtins)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$ find /file/collection/*/logs/ -name "*.log" -type f -maxdepth 1 | xargs grep hello
```

Comment: Siju, "xargs" doesn't seems to be working on this environment

Comment: @PiyushWakhale see https://stackoverflow.com/a/18647755/4082052

Comment: i removed -maxdepth flag and it worked, thanx :)