# Bash permutation with list of words

Tags: bash, permutation

I have a phrase like this:

`The quick brown $UNKNOWN1 jumps over the $UNKNOWN2 dog`

And I have a worldlist like this:

```
me
black
lazy
swan
dog
word
sky
fox
nothing
you
```

How can I permute the list in bash to have all the permutations like:

`The quick brown you jumps over the nothing dog`

`The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog`

and so on, all permutations.
I tried with some for loops but got stuck because I think i need some loop inside a loop (nested loop).
Something like:

```
for i in `cat wordlist.txt`;
  do echo "The quick brown $i jumps over the $UNKNOWN2 dog";
done
```

EDIT:

I think this is it:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in `cat wordlist.txt`
  do
    for a in `cat wordlist.txt`
      do
        echo "The quick brown $i jumps over the $a dog"
    done
done
```

Comment: What have you tried? At which step did you get stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think i need some loop inside a loop.

You're right:

```
for i in $(cat wordlist.txt)
do
  for j in $(cat wordlist.txt)
  do
    echo "The quick brown $i jumps over the $j dog"
  done
done
```

You can optionally avoid it when `$i = $j`:

```
for i in $(cat wordlist.txt); do
  for j in $(cat wordlist.txt); do
    if [ "$i" != "$j" ]; then
      echo "The quick brown $i jumps over the $j dog"
    fi
  done
done
```

Comment: Yes, just got to almost this thinking better, I'll set this as answer.

Comment: Yes! The second example is even better, I don't need same words in the phrase.

Answer (score 5):

Just for fun, **GNU Parallel** is good at permutations too:

```
parallel echo The quick brown {1} jumps over the {2} dog :::: wordlist.txt :::: wordlist.txt
```

Or, the same, but omitting lines where the two words are the same:

```
parallel 'bash -c "[ {1} != {2} ] && echo The quick brown {1} jumps over the {2} dog"' :::: wordlist.txt wordlist.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

There is also a hacky alternative with no loops:

```
printf "The quick brown %s jumps over the %s dog.\n" $(join -j 2 words words)
```

In this case, `join` creates the cartesian product of the word list with itself. The result is a list of words. Each of these words is passed as an argument to `printf`.
`printf` prints the sentence, replacing `%s` with the next word from the list. After printing the sentence once, it still has unread words and continues until all words are printed.

**Benefits:**

- Shorter program
- Faster than loops

**Drawbacks** (exactly the same as for `for i in $(cat wordlist)`)

- May fail on long word lists due to [max. number of arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18647755/6770384).
- If the word list contains `*` or `?` these might be expanded by `bash`.
- Words from the word list have to be real words, whitespace is not allowed.