# env: python: Argument list too long

Tags: python

I'm having trouble with python installed in my iMac. The terminal outputted the same error message:

```
env: python: Argument list too long
```

even for a simple command like `python -V`

The terminal would froze for a moment, and then outputted the error message above. Help please.

Comment: Did you got the answer, I faced the same issue today. i have seen some related question answers which suggest to delete *.PDF files.  this didn't worked for me. Are you able to go fwd?

Answer (score 0):

Probable duplicate of [Argument list too long error for rm, cp, mv commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11289551/argument-list-too-long-error-for-rm-cp-mv-commands).

One possible reason could be `python` is an alias for some other command. Try `\python -V`. To find what was being run for `python` run `alias python`.