# Remove files in directory and ignore if empty-BASH

Tags: bash, glob

By using the command :

```
rm /file_path/*.csv
```

I can delete all csv files in the required folder.However if the directory is empty or there are no csv files I get the following error:

```
No such file or directory
```

How do I avoid this error?I have this logic in a script with certain downstream dependancies so throwing this error will cause the rest of my code to stop.Whats the best way in bash to delete files only if they exist in the directory?

Comment: Why is this tagged python?

Comment: If you search on the phrase "bash check if file exists", you’ll find resources that can explain it much better than we can in an answer here.

Comment: @JohnGordon oh I though OP wants handle problem in a python code.

Comment: `man rm`. Use option `-f`?

Answer (score 3):

Another variant is to check if your folder is empty before to run your script:

```
find file_path/ -type d -empty
```

It returns the name of your folder if it is empty.

Or use the "-f" option with rm command if you want only avoid the error message:

Without:

```
rm -r file_path/*.csv
rm: cannot remove ‘file_path/*.csv’: No such file or directory
```

With:

```
rm -rf file_path/*.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

See [Test whether a glob has any matches in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2937407/4154375) for ways to check if `/file_path/*.csv` matches anything.  However, even if you do such a test before running the `rm` command it may fail if the directory has a very large number of CSV files.  See [Argument list too long error for rm, cp, mv commands](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11289551/4154375).

If you have a modern version of `find`, this is a reliable and efficient option:

```
find /file_path -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.csv' -delete
```

Answer (score -2):

You can do: `[ -f /file_path/*.csv ] && rm /file_path/*.csv`