# Passing very long text as argument to a bash script file

Tags: linux

I got error "Argument list too long" when I pass a very long text as an argument to a script.  For example:

```
./myScript.bash "${v_very_long_text}"
```

Is that a way to fix the error?
thanks

Comment: rewrite your script to consume stdin

Comment: Probably you have to change the way how to pass the data to your script. Show the code of your script and sample contents of `v_very_long_text` to get suggestions.

Comment: Or rewrite the script to read from a file, and make the filename the argument.

Comment: Reading from stdin would allow putting the string in a here-doc

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Argument list too long error for rm, cp, mv commands](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11289551/608639)

Answer (score -2):

**Method 1:**

```
echo "${v_very_long_text}" > text_file.txt
./myScript.bash $(cat text_file.txt)
```

**Method 2:**

```
tee text_file.txt <<EOF
line 1
line 2
line 3
EOF

./myScript.bash $(cat text_file.txt)
```