# How to copy files name/path containing spaces in unix?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, cp, file-copying

My target is to search the files containing a pattern and copy it to a folder. The files may available in many folders from a folder (say /home/abc/logs/ ....). Some file names and folders carry spacial characters including white spaces. I am trying to assign the result found to a variable and copy it. But result is "Argument list too long"

Linux server

```
pattern="somesttring" ;
LOG_FILE_PATH="/path/to/logs/"
LOGS_TO_COPY=$(grep -Hrn "$pattern" "$LOG_FILE_PATH" | cut -d: -f1)
cp $LOGS_TO_COPY temp #temp is folder to which i have to copy
```

I am getting the below error:

```
cp $LOGS_TO_COPY temp/
-bash: /bin/cp: Argument list too long
```

Comment: @tripleee: I can't see either of those questions being a dupe. Quoting alone will not preserve the distinction between argument separator and bona-fide whitespace in the output of `grep`. If I am missing which part of the dupes answers this question's problem, please demonstrate. (Note that the immediately obvious answer of `cp "$LOGS_TO_COPY" temp/` is wrong.)

Comment: Added another duplicate. You seem to be looking for `grep -rl "$pattern" "$LOG_FILE_PATH" | xargs cp -t temp/`

Comment: @tripleee I'd be happy with any of the options I listed. That link is at least relevant, though not directly a solution of this (`grep` having `--null` option needs to be at least a comment). Given that producing the correct solution is clearly not as trivial as it seems, I'll vote to reopen, though the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11289551/argument-list-too-long-error-for-rm-cp-mv-commands) is quite useful to explain the whys and the generalities. (My other comment was deleted as incorrect.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't store it in variable, at least not a normal string variable. There is no way for the string variable to keep the difference between the space inside each argument and the space delimiting them.

```
grep -lr "$pattern" "$LOG_FILE_PATH" | while IFS= read -r file; do cp "$file" temp/; done
```

Also note that you don't need to cut the grep result, as the `-l` flag gives you just the file names, exactly what you wanted. `-H` is the default so it's not needed, and `-n` is unnecessary if you're just going to cut it off.

This will not work if you have files containing newline in their names. As a solution, you can tell `grep` (and `read`) to use NUL for delimiter.

```
grep -lr --null "$pattern" "$LOG_FILE_PATH" | while IFS= read -d $'\0' -r file; do cp "$file" temp/; done
```

Alternately, you can use `xargs` instead of `while`+`read`:

```
grep -lr --null "$pattern" "$LOG_FILE_PATH" | xargs --null -I {} cp {} temp/
```

If you *have to* store it in a variable, use the same pattern as above to store it into an *array* variable. This way space is not needed as the argument delimiter.

```
declare -a files
while IFS= read -d $'\0' -r file; do files+=("$file"); done < <(grep -lr --null "$pattern" "$LOG_FILE_PATH")
cp "${files[@]}" temp/
```

Here's another way to do it (though this will not work if filenames include newline characters, as `mapfile` does not support changing the delimiter):

```
mapfile -t files < <(grep -lr "$pattern" "$LOG_FILE_PATH")
cp "${files[@]}" temp/
```

If the number of files to copy is very big, the `while` and `xargs` solutions will still work, but those that simply plop the entire array into one `cp` command may not.

Comment: Thanks for the solution.
Here, when i run the command --> grep -Hrn "$pattern" "$LOG_FILE_PATH"
number of files found is 22584(in my case)
where when i ran your command(1st command with while), the number of files found is 329
SO i feel many files are missing

Comment: As I said, `grep -Hrn` shows each line where there is a match. You then cut off the line and the content using `cut`, so if 100 lines match, you will have the same file name 100 times. I haven't thought about it, but this will also be the reason your command line is too long. `grep -l` will only display each file name once. Try to compare `grep -lr ... | wc -l` with the deduped version of your list: `grep -Hrn ... | cut ... | sort | uniq | wc -l`.

Comment: Pasting here the results obtained
grep -lr "$pattern" "$LOG_FILE_PATH" | while IFS= read -r file; do cp "$file" .; done
ll | wc -l
330


##############

grep -Hrn "$pattern" "$LOG_FILE_PATH"| sort | uniq | wc -l
22598


###############

grep -Hrn "$pattern" "$LOG_FILE_PATH" | wc -l
22598

Comment: You missed the cut sort uniq step to see how many _different_ files you’re getting.