# how to combine ls and find command?

Tags: bash, find, ls

What do I need to do if I want to list all the files (not directories) and their size, with their sizes sorted from largest to smallest? I tried `find . -type f -exec ls -Shl {} \;` but it does list the files in order (of their size). Anyone can help??

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/53737/how-to-list-all-files-ordered-by-size

Comment: Try `find . -type f -printf '%k %P | sort -g`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `+` instead of `\;`.

```
find . -type f -exec ls -Shl {} +
```

`\;` calls ls once per file whereas `+` calls it a single time with all the matched file names.

Comment: The `+` does not process all files, well that depends on how much files is there to process. With the `+` find will process as much files as possible while avoiding `argmax` see https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/argmax/  You know the error that says `list arguments too long` see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11289551/argument-list-too-long-error-for-rm-cp-mv-commands