# Unable to delete thousands of files within a folder in terminal

Tags: command-line, terminal, command, command-line-arguments, rm

I'm trying to delete files inside a certain folder but it's throwing an error:

```
rm -rf /usr/html/sched/downloads/*

-bash: /bin/rm: Argument list too long
```

I searched online and found this solution but I'm afraid to try it being a production server and I don't know how to put the path correctly:

```
find . -name '*' | xargs rm -v
```

How can I delete thousands of files within the `/downloads` director? FYI, there's no sub-directory.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Argument list too long error for rm, cp, mv commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11289551/argument-list-too-long-error-for-rm-cp-mv-commands)

Comment: Will this command work? `find . -name "/usr/html/sched/downloads/*" -delete`

Comment: You would probably rather do `find /usr/html/sched/downloads -type f -delete`; you can replace `-delete` with `-print` first so see if the files are the right ones. Notice that `-delete` is a) a GNU find extension and b) can only delete files, not directories.

Comment: Could you post this as an answer? I got it working. Thank you :)

Comment: It's an exact duplicate of what I posted, can you accept the duplicate instead?

Answer (score 0):

I think here you can check how you can handle it because for a large scale of files you will need to do it by a specific quantity by milliseconds.

```
find ./cache -mtime +0.5 -print0 | xargs -0 rm -f
```

[Faster way to delete a large number of files [duplicate]](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/96937)

Comment: Will this work: `find rm -rf /usr/html/sched/downloads/* -mtime +0.5 -print0 | xargs -0 rm -f`

Comment: Link only answers are not allowed on SO. [answer] Either form your own answer or delete this altogether.