# How do I create the same directory in every subdirectories in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I've been trying to create the directory "a" inside all the subdirectories of "example".

What I tried is the following:

```
mkdir example/*/a
```

But it doesn't take the '*' as a wildcard, returning mkdir: can not create «example/*/a» directory: It doesn't exist file or directory

Note that I have too much subdirectories in example, so I can't do it by creating a list.

I don't want to do it with for loops, because I'm learning bash and I'm not allowed to use loops. Probably, there is no way to avoid a for loop, in that case, please tell me :).

Thank you.

Comment: _they are not fast enough_  : How many million of directories are you trying to create, so that speed is an issue? I think a loop is the fastest way.

Comment: "they are not fast enough".  If you have performance concerns, you probably shouldn't be using a shell at all.

Comment: @WilliamPursell and user1934428: I'm a computer engineering student and I'm currently learning bash. So, I've been taught that loops in bash, as it is dynamically typed, may be avoided if there is another way of doing it. So I have a task of moving a lot of files to other directories that I have to create without using loops. I understand your point, but I'm just learning, I'm not into business stuff.  Anyway, thank you for your contributions :)

Comment: The performance issue in this case comes not from looping but from running `mkdir` individually for each directory to be created.  On my [Cygwin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygwin) system, for example, a single `mkdir` takes around a 10th of a second to run.  Even 100 directories is a big deal.  Solutions that invoke `mkdir` just once, or a minimum number of times, are *very much quicker*.  Using a loop to create input for `xargs -0 mkdir` would probably give acceptable performance.  Don't worry about the performance of loops until you have found, and analyzed the causes of, real problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
dirs=( example/*/ )
mkdir -v "${dirs[@]/%/a}"
```

- `dirs=( example/*/ )` creates an array of all the subdirectories of `example` ( `(example/dir1/ example/dir2/ ...)` ).
- `"${dirs[@]/%/a}"` expands to a list containing all the elements of `dirs` with an `a` appended to each of them ( `(example/dir1/a example/dir2/a ...)` ).

---

If you have a *very* large number of subdirectories the `mkdir` in the code above may fail with an "Argument list too long" error.  See [Argument list too long error for rm, cp, mv commands](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11289551/4154375).

One way to avoid the problem is to pass a NUL-terminated list of the directories to be created to `xargs -0`:

```
dirs=( example/*/ )
printf '%s\0' "${dirs[@]/%/a}" | xargs -0 mkdir -v
```

That will, if necessary, run multiple `mkdir` commands, each with an argument list that does not exceed the limit.

However, if the number of directories is *that* large you may run into performance problems due to Bash (unnecessarily, but unavoidably) sorting the list produced by `example/*/`).  In that case it would be better to use `find`.  One way to do it is:

```
find example -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -printf '%p/a\0' | xargs -0 mkdir -v
```

`find` has built-in support for `xargs`-like behaviour with `-exec ... +`.  However, it's a bit fiddly to use in this case.  The best I can come up with  in a hurry is:

```
find example -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d    \
    -exec bash -c 'mkdir -v "${@/%//a}"' bash {} +
```

Since it adds `/a` to all of the arguments passed to `bash` by `find` before  running `mkdir` on them, it may encounter an "Argument list too long" error anyway.  I'll leave it here because it illustrates a sometimes-useful technique, but I recommend against using it.

Answer (score 2):

> Probably, there is no way to avoid a for loop

You can use `find`:

```sh
find example -type d -not -name a -exec mkdir -p {}/a \;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just:

```
for i in example/*/; do
    mkdir "$i"/a
done
```

Comment: You probably want: `test -d "$i" && mkdir "$i"/a`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can only avoid a loop if you already know the subdirectories under `example`, e.g.:

```
mkdir example/{subdir1,subdir2,subdir3}/a
```

Otherwise, use a for loop to the rescue:

```
for d in example/*/; do mkdir "${d}a"; done
```

Note: add a `-v` to `mkdir` if you want it to show you the directories that get created.