# Getting Argument list too long in jenkins

Tags: shell, jenkins, command-line-arguments

I am getting following exception all of a sudden from Jenkins.

```
*Building in workspace /data/jenkins/workspace/BIG_QUERY_TABLE_CREATE_PROCESSOR/table_name/xxxxxx
[xxxxx] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/jenkins2448049600259551489.sh
FATAL: command execution failed
java.io.IOException: error=7, Argument list too long
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:247)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
Caused: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/bin/sh" (in directory "/data/jenkins/workspace/BIG_QUERY_TABLE_CREATE_PROCESSOR/table_name/xxxxx"): error=7, Argument list too long
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:252)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:221)
    at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:996)
```

I have used table name as a user defined axis variable to pass the value of table name.

`java -server -Xms256m -Xmx512m -Dquarkus.http.port=0 -classpath ".:/opt/xxx/xxxx-jar/machine-learning-xxxx-cluster-computation-jar-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-allinone.jar" com.xxxx.dataflow.xxxx.bigquery.admin.processor.main.BigqueryTableCreateProcessorMain -c ALL -p xxxxxx -d ${DATASET} -t ${table_name} -a 1 –`

How to resolve it?

Comment: This is most likely not a Jenkins issue, rather a shell command issue, which has a [character limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11289551/argument-list-too-long-error-for-rm-cp-mv-commands). Post the shell step content to understand details.

Comment: java -server  -Xms256m -Xmx512m -Dquarkus.http.port=0 -classpath ".:/opt/xxx/xxxx-jar/machine-learning-xxxx-cluster-computation-jar-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-allinone.jar"  com.xxxx.dataflow.xxxx.bigquery.admin.processor.main.BigqueryTableCreateProcessorMain -c ALL -p xxxxxx -d ${DATASET} -t ${table_name} -a 1

Comment: Above is the command

Comment: Even If I submit a simple echo command, I get the same exception.

Comment: What is the trailing dash about "`... -a 1 –`" ? Typically on a unix command a dash expects a parameter or represents a command from `stdin`. Does that even work outside Jenkins, from a regular shell command line?

Comment: `${DATASET}` might be the problem since it could expand into many arguments.

Answer (score 0):

The issue must not rely in your shell statement - all the environment and parameter variables are injected into the shell when starting an **sh** command.
So, if any of your other envs or params is very long, the shell command exits with this error message.

You could use the below mentioned code before your sh command to check your build variables:

```
this.env.getEnvironment().each { name, value -> println "env.$name = $value" }
this.params.each { name, value -> println "params.$name = $value" }
```