# Concatenating files, getting "argument list is too long"

Tags: bash, for-loop, find

I have around 250,000 files whose file names look like: `read_\d\d.fasta`

I get the `argument is too long` error when running `cat *.fasta > all.fasta` command.

Normally I use a `for` loop or `find` when I get the `argument is too long` error.

How can I use a for loop (or any other method) to concatenate this number of files?

I have tried `for i in read*fasta ; do cat $i >> combined.$i ; done` However this doesn't concatenate the files.

I have looked at other answers when looking as this error, however I don't see how `for/find` can be used here.

Comment: `for` solution: `for f in *.fasta ; do cat "$f"; done > all.fasta`

Comment: `gnu find` solution: `find . -type f -name '*.fasta' -exec cat {} + > all.fasta`. Add options `-mindepth` and/or `-maxdepth`to limit directory depth.

Comment: `find` solution: `find . -type f -name '*.fasta' -print0 | xargs -0  cat > all.fasta`

Comment: See [Argument list too long error for rm, cp, mv commands](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11289551/4154375).

Comment: Keep in mind the race condition that allows `all.fasta` to be treated as a result of `*.fasta`, which could result in an infinite loop that fills your file system.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
printf '%s\0' *.fasta | xargs -0 cat -- > all.fasta
```

- Using NUL characters as path delimiters (`\0` in the `printf` format string, `-0` option for `xargs`) means that this will work for arbitrary filenames, including ones that contain newlines.
- The `--` after `cat` means that it will work even if some of the files have names that begin with `-`.
- `printf` avoids the "argument is too long" error because it is a shell built-in.  Unlike external commands such as `cat`, built-ins do not use the [exec system call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exec_(system_call)), and the argument length limitation is in "exec".

Comment: I would expect `printf` to have the same problem, as it's another simple command that receives each result from `*.fasta` as a separate argument.

Comment: @chepner, `printf` doesn't have the problem because it is a shell built-in.  The limitation is associated with the "exec" system call, which is used to run a `cat` command but not `printf`.  As always, I tested the code before posting it.

Comment: I assumed you did, but I would consider this an undocumented optimization, not something to rely on. `printf`, built-in or not, is still part of a *simple* command, and should be assumed to have the same semantics as any other command. (It's not a special *compound* command like `for` or `[[ ... ]]`.)

Comment: @chepner, I disagree.  `printf` is documented as a Bash built-in.  "exec" is not used for built-ins.  I think the code is safe in all versions of Bash, and always will be.

Comment: Ah, ok, sorry. I was confusing `printf` not needing `exec` with `printf` expanding the glob itself (which is, I think, what `for f in *.fasta` does).

Comment: @chepner, sorry for my lack of clarity.  I've added a note to my answer to try to improve it.  Thanks for taking the time to point out the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -name read_\[0-9\]\[0-9\].fasta -print0 | xargs -0 cat > all.fasta
```

This combination of `find` and `xargs` should safely find these files without exceeding `execv()` limits and avoid an infinite loop.

- The `.` for `find` should be your directory of 250k files.
- The `-name` matches your pattern, specifically "read_\d\d.fasta".
- The `print0` makes the output null terminated and therefore safe.
- Calling `xargs` with `-0` receives null terminated and calls `cat` on each.

This works in Linux and FrreBSD (presumably also other *BSD).