# How to solve issue Argument list too long in grep command?

Tags: linux, bash, grep, find, xargs

How to solve issue Argument list too long in grep command?

I need to execute grep command

```
grep '^ORA'  '/log/bssuser/CDR/Postpaid_CDR_Log/'*.log > output.txt
```

I have error :
-bash: /usr/bin/xargs: Argument list too long

Comment: The command-line you provided in your post only mentions `grep`, not `xargs`.

Comment: As you can see from the text of the error message (.... **xargs**: ...), it does not come from the command you have posted. Please post the command which causes the trouble.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Argument list too long error for rm, cp, mv commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11289551/argument-list-too-long-error-for-rm-cp-mv-commands)

Answer (score 1):

For handling a wild number of files you need to use `find`:

```bash
find /log/bssuser/CDR/Postpaid_CDR_Log/ -type f -name '*.log' \
     -exec grep '^ORA' {} + >  output.txt
```