# How to delete a type of file in all sub directories/sub directories

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to delete all files of .m4a in the music directory, but the problem is it would take a while since  I have to get inside every single directory (artist and albums are sub directories) to delete the files that end with m4a. In some sub directory, there is another folder.

If I'm in the music directory, is there a command to delete ALL files with *m4a in every single sub directory and inside the folder that is in sub directory WITHOUT going in there? I'm already aware the command to delete all m4a files which is

```
rm *m4a
```

But this command only works if I go inside every single sub directory. I'm looking for a command that deletes all *m4a files without going inside every single sub directory/folder.

Answer (score 3):

It is simple.

Use this command:
`find /path/to/directory -type f -name "*.m4a" -delete`.

Comment: I recommend running it without the `-delete` first, so it'll print a list of files it'll delete, and you can sanity-check for anything you don't want to delete. If it looks good, *then* rerun with the `-delete` action.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the globstar operator (**) in your ~/.bashrc file:

```
# If set, the pattern "**" used in a pathname expansion context will
# match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.
shopt -s globstar
```

Uncomment the globstar line, and then you can write:

```
rm /path/to/directory/**/*.m4a
```

But before doing so, you 'll have to source ~/.bashrc that first time:

```
. ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: This will often work, but it may fail with an "argument list too long" error if there are very many `.m4a` files.  See [Argument list too long error for rm, cp, mv commands](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11289551/4154375).