# Unix tar returns The parameter list is too long

Tags: linux, shell, unix, tar

When I try to tar all the file in a folder using fowing command:

**tar cvf mailpdfs.tar *.pdf**

The shell complains:

**ksh: /usr/bin/tar: 0403-027 The parameter list is too long.**

How to deal with it? My folder contain 25000 pdf files, each file is 2MB in size, how can I copy them very fast?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Argument list too long error for rm, cp, mv commands](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11289551/608639), [Unix cp argument list too long](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5892339/608639), etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can copy/move all the pdf files to a newfolder and then tar the newfolder.

```
mv *.pdf newfolder

tar cvf mailpdfs.tar newfolder
```

[Referenced from unix.com](https://www.unix.com/unix-for-dummies-questions-and-answers/27167-arg-list-too-long-when-trying-tar-files.html)

Answer (score 1):

The tar option `-T` is what you need

```
   -T, --files-from=FILE
          get names to extract or create from FILE
```

You are blowing the limit for file globbing in ksh, so you can generate the list of files like this

```
ls | grep '\.pdf$' >files.txt
```

Then use that file with tar

```
tar cvf mailpdfs.tar -T files.txt
```

Finally, you can do away with creating a temporary file to hold the filenames by getting tar to read them from stdin (by giving the `-T` option the special filename `-`).

So we end up with this

```
ls | grep '\.pdf$' | tar cvf mailpdfs.tar -T -
```

Comment: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Comment: In this way, special characters in the file name are no longer a problem: `find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*.pdf" -print0 | tar --null -cf mailpdfs.tar -T -`